# warning C4700: uninitialized local variable

Tags: c++

When I compile it says "warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'count' used".
I am not sure why it is saying this and I did not come on here so someone can do my homework.
just looking for help with this one error, I know it has to do with the function definition ReadStudentData or in Main.

thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct StudentType
{string studentName;
int testScore;//Between 0 and 100
char grade;


}student[20];

void PrintNameHeader(ostream& out);
bool OpenInputFile(ifstream& inFile, string& infilename ); //OPEN input file
void Pause();// Pause
void ReadStudentData(ifstream& infile, StudentType student[], int& );// Read student infp including first and last name and test score
void AssignGrades(StudentType student[], int);//assign grades to each student
int HighestScore(const StudentType student[], int );//Get the highest scores
void PrintNamesWithHighestScore(const StudentType student[], int);//Print name with highest Scores
void DisplayAllStudents(const StudentType student[], int);//Display all students
void GetLowHighRangeValues(int& , int&);//for example a student types 50 100 , it will get all students within that range
void DisplayStudentsInRange(const StudentType student[], int, int, int);// display students in that range
void SortStudentsByName(StudentType student[], int);// sort students by name
void SortStudentsByScore(StudentType student[], int);// sort students by test score highest to lowest


const int NUM_STUDENTS = 20;

int main()
{

    ifstream infile;
    string inFilename;

    int count = 0;

    StudentType student[NUM_STUDENTS];

    int numStudents;


    PrintNameHeader(cout);

    OpenInputFile(infile,inFilename);

    ReadStudentData(infile, student, numStudents);

    AssignGrades(student, numStudents);

    return 0;
}

//Function definitions

void PrintNameHeader(ostream& out)
{
    //Display name header on screen
    cout << "name" << endl;



}
bool OpenInputFile(ifstream& inFile, string& infilename)
{



    cout << "Enter the name of the .txt file that you want to open for input.\n";
    cout << "Do not put spaces in the file name ";
    cin >> infilename;
    cout << endl;


    inFile.open(infilename.c_str());
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Sorry, the input file " << infilename <<" was not found"<< endl;\
            return false;   
    }

    cout << "Input file " << infilename << " is open for reading.\n\n";
    return true;     
}

void Pause()
{
    cout << endl;

    cin.ignore(80, '\n');

    cout<<"Please hit the enter key to continue...\n";

    cin.get();

}

void ReadStudentData(ifstream& infile, StudentType student[], int& numstudents)
{
    string firstName,
        LastName,
        testScore;

    int count = 0;


    if( infile)

        for (int count; count < NUM_STUDENTS; count++)
        {
            cin >> firstName[count] >> LastName[count] >> testScore[count];

            student[count].studentName = firstName +  ", " + LastName;

        }




        numstudents = count;
        cout << numstudents << endl;




}
void AssignGrades(StudentType student[], int numstudents)
{

    int i;
    for(i=0;i< NUM_STUDENTS;i++)
        switch((int)(student[i].testScore/10))
    {case 10:
    case 9: student[i].grade='A';
        break;
    case 8: student[i].grade='B';
        break;
    case 7: student[i].grade='C';
        break;
    case 6: student[i].grade='D';
        break;
    default: student[i].grade='F';
        break;
    }

}
int HighestScore(const StudentType student[], int numstudents)
{
    int max=0,i;

    for(i=1;i<numstudents;i++)
    {
        if(student[i].testScore>student[max].testScore)
            max=i;
    }

    return max;

}
void PrintNamesWithHighestScore(const StudentType student[], int numstudents)
{

}
void DisplayAllStudents(const StudentType student[], int numstudents)
{

}
void GetLowHighRangeValues(int& lowRange, int& highRange)
{

}

void DisplayStudentsInRange(const StudentType student[], int numStudents, int lownum, int highNum)
{

}

void SortStudentsByName(StudentType student[], int numStudents)
{

}

void SortStudentsByScore(StudentType student[], int numstudents)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to this:

```
for (int count; count < NUM_STUDENTS; count++)
//   ^^^^^^^^^
```

You may need to initialize `count`, presumably to `0`:

```
for (int count = 0; count < NUM_STUDENTS; count++)
```

or maybe you mean to use the same `count` declared in the outer block:

```
for (; count < NUM_STUDENTS; count++)
```

Comment: oh yea duh cant believe i missed that, thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

You define another count variable inside the for, which is not initialized. you should either initialize it in for:

```
for (int count = 0; count < NUM_STUDENTS; count++)
```

or remove the declaration if you need it in the outside scope:

```
for (; count < NUM_STUDENTS; count++)
```

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ have two distinct components of preparing a variable/object for use. Declaration and initialization.

These are declarations:

```
int i;
Object o;
struct Foo;
```

These declare things, they don't tell the compiler what values they should start with. The following is legal:

```
int meaning;
if (day == "Thursday")
    meaning = 42;
else
    meaning = 0;
```

This code ensures that meaning *always* has a value.

Unfortunately, in C and C++ primitive types, like ints, etc, do not have nice, safe, default values. So if you wrote:

```
int meaning;
if (day == "Thursday")
    meaning = 42;
else if (day == "Friday")
    meaning = 0;
```

What is the value of "meaning" when day is "Monday"? If you're thinking of a number, you're wrong. The answer is: It's undefined.

The compiler will let you build code like this, but it will provide the error you've seen to help you protect yourself.

To declare AND initialize a variable at the same time, simply do:

```
int meaning = 0;
if (day == "Thursday")
    meaning = 42;
```

In your code, the problem was this:

```
for (int count; count < NUM_STUDENTS; ++count)
```

this should be

```
for (int count = 0; count < NUM_STUDENTS; ++count)
```

otherwise, the program might compile but the initial value of "count" could be any number from -2^31 to +2^31.